# Single tab to display multiple different widget panel options

Tags: python, pyqt5

The project is based in Python 3.7.

I'm working on a project that requires the use of the tabs widget. Lets say I have two tabs. On tab 1 there is a drop down menu with two different options. I need these two options to determine what will be displayed on tab 2. For example, if option 1 on tab 1 is selected then tab 2 could show a simple list or, if option 2 on tab 1 were selected then tab 2 will show a check box.

My naive thought it I might be able to create three different widget panels, each with the required widgets and displays for tab 2. Then a simple if/else check could determine which option number is selected and thus which widget panel to display can be selected. This is a guess at best though and I'm not sure how one would implement this.

Comment: Your issue is a bit unclear. For example, what if the user clicks on the second tab before selecting *any* option in the first tab? In any case, you could consider using a [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) for the second tab, and then use [`setCurrentWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#setCurrentWidget) or [`setCurrentIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) to select the appropriate tab.

Comment: In the case where a user clicks on tab 2 before making a selection I was just going to have a default blank widget with a simple text instructing them to go back or see if there is a way to grey out the tab and block access to it.
Thank you for the QStackedWidget information, I will check that out. That looks like it is exactly what I need.